# Copy newly inserted entry into one database table, into a separate databases table.

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have two databases, **db1** which is in MS SQL, and **db2** which is in MYSQL and accessed via phpMyAdmin.

Both databases share a common table, with the same exact same name and structure.

When I insert a new entry into **db1**, I want it also to be inserted into **db2** at the same time. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: can't you catch `last inserted id` and use it to insert to MySQL ? [stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53071/how-to-extract-the-last-inserted-row-in-sql-server?rq=1) has many topics with this

Comment: If you just want the same entry in both tables, why not insert them at the  same time?